# Cannot find libsqlite3.dylib in Xcode 4.4.1

Tags: ios5.1, xcode4.4

I'm doing a small project using sqlite db in iOS. But the problem is now, when I go to build phase and Link Binary -> +  there is no any library called 'libsqlite3.dylib'. Please any one help me. I'm in really trouble situation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

what's the xcode version you use? i use 4.4.1 version and i can find libsqlite3.dylib. so i think just try upgrade your xcode.

Comment: at the first time I can found,, in that case I used Deployment target as 4.3,, but I create another project using target platform as 4.0, when I try to add the library it showed as a different icon, but I add that lib it gave an error which saying 'undefined symbol for architecture 1386:'. So I quite the Xcode and re opened,, Then I cannot found even that library. I also used Xcode 4.4.1

Comment: normally, the error caused by linking error, which means that you haven't link resources to your project. but you said you cann't find libsqlite. in fact, i changed target platform to 4.0,then i still can find libsqlite. so this shouldn't be the reason for this problem. i just think that give your another try to add libsqlite manually. or maybe this problem caused by another reason that you haven't realized. pls check the framework and setting again.